# Optimising a very frequently used query that searches on date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a web application(Rails) that uses postgres and it has table `openings`.

`openings` table has a few attributes and the ones relevant to this query are `valid_till` - datetime and 'is_downloaded' - boolean.

Now in almost each page request I have to check if there are **any**  -- valid undownloaded openings.

An opening is valid and undownloaded if `valid_till` is less than or equal to `current_time` and `is_downloaded` is false.

```
SELECT  "openings".*  
FROM "openings" 
WHERE (valid_till >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and is_downloaded IS false) 
LIMIT 1
```

I have constructed an sql query I just want to optimize it the best I can since it will be used almost on every page request. `openings` table is going to get huge number of records, as time passes by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want an index.  I would suggest:

```
create index idx_openings_isdownloaded_validtill on openings(is_downloaded, valid_till)
```

However, I would caution that using `limit` without an `order by` is usually a bad idea.  Without the `order by`, it returns an indeterminate matching row.

EDIT:

A Jmelesky suggests, a filtered/partial index is probably better for this query:

```
create index idx_openings_isdownloaded_validtill
    on openings(valid_till)
    where not is_downloaded;
```

Comment: what do you mean by indeterminate?. I really dont care what row it returns, I just want to check if there is a single row that matches this criteria

Comment: @coderVishal . . . One matching row will be returned.  If you run the query again, a different row might be returned.

Comment: ok got it, for the current implementation it really does not matter to me. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Indexes on booleans are often not great. I'd be more tempted by a partial index: `create index on openings (valid_till) where is_downloaded is false`. That should be small and fast.

Comment: @coderVishal I agree with jmelesky. If the condition `is_downloaded = false` reduces the number of rows substantially then a partial index would be more effective

Comment: @jmelesky . . . I'm not sure it would be *more* effective, but for this query, a partial index is clearly a good idea.  The index is not just on a boolean; that is only the first column.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in almost each page request I have to check if there are any -- valid undownloaded openings.

Then it would be more appropriate to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT  NULL FROM "openings" 
                        WHERE valid_till >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                              and is_downloaded IS false)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END
```

The benefit of `EXISTS` is that the compiler can optimize away any computations that have no bearing on whether a matching record exists or not.  You're also not returning any unnecessary data by selecting `*` - you're just transmitting one scalar value over the wire.

The best way to improve the performance of this specific query is to have a compound index on `(valid_till, is_downloaded)`.

Comment: is the case statement necessary since exists will return a boolean value anyway.

Comment: Yeah but I don't like to have to remember if `true` gets translated as 1 or 0 so I tend to be explicit.  If you find that it makes a performance impact you're free to change it.

Comment: do you think adding an order by will help? Say if the openings have been ordered by ascending valid_till. As soon as postgres finds am opening that fails the condition `valid_till >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it need not check other openings

Comment: No, the compiler will do that for you.  `ORDER BY` only affects the _output_  It will not make the `WHERE` clause perform any faster.